# How can I deploy a model that i trained on amazon sagemaker locally?

Tags: tensorflow, mxnet, amazon-sagemaker

I trained a model using aws blazingtext algorithm on amazon sagemaker and I was able to deploy an endpoint using sagemaker. However, in my circumstance this is not cost-efficient and I would like to run it locally. I have found the documentation on this to be confusing.

What I have is the trained model saved as a "model.tar.gz" file that I have downloaded from my s3 bucket. I have read online that you can deploy models using tensorflow and docker images, but I simply want to deploy the model I have created using sagemaker using my local machine. Essentially what I want to do is :

```py
predictor = sagemaker.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='local_cpu')
```

I expect to be able to use the predict function to make inference calls and return responses with the prediction results. I am looking for which libraries to use, and the associated code to accomplish this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

SageMaker BlazingText comes in 2 flavors:

1. a supervised version, that learns to classify variable-length token sequences and
2. an unsupervised version, that learns token embeddings.

[According to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html), for both versions, the binaries produced by the model can be consumed by fastText. From [`fasttext` python binding documentation](https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py/blob/master/README.md) it seems that the following command will work for both situations:

```
import fasttext

# bin file is found in the model.tar.gz produced by Sagemaker
model = fasttext.load_model('model_filename.bin')

# inference for unsupervised version
model['king']

# inference for supervised version
model.predict('Which baking dish is best to bake a banana bread ?')
```

[Gensim seems to have similar ability to read fastText artifacts](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#module-gensim.models.fasttext) but I found the API a little less clear and it seems to be available only for the unsupervised case (word embeddings)